# Detect aluminum using an inductive sensor

Tags: sensor, inductive, detection

I was wondering if you can use an inductive proximity sensor to detect aluminum or if a capacitive sensor must be used? I wasn't sure if inductive sensors were reserved for ferrous metals only.

Answer (score 7):

I've used years ago an inductive proximity sensor for a test, and I remember that it sensed aluminium and copper way better than iron.

Just found [this](http://www.rselectronics.com/SEO/Selecting_Prox.pdf) doc.

Answer (score 6):

Yes - inductive sensors work on the same principles as a comercially avaliable metal detector. They have an LC circuit which oscillates in a particular frequencey range, when a conductive material is near by, eddy currents form in the material which then produce their own magnetic field which then dampens the oscillation of the sensor.